# How do I upgrade from a rather old (17.04) version of Ubuntu to the current version?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I have had a old partition of Ubuntu running 17.04 that I haven't booted to in ages. I finally booted back into it the other day and wanted to know how do I upgrade? The software updater doesn't work anymore. I assume because the software sources are taken down. How do I update the sources? And which one should I update them to to have a safe upgrade? Perhaps I could set my sources to 18.04 first and do that upgrade?

[image: Error message in software updater]

```
christopher@Chris-Gaming-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for christopher: 
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release
  404  Not Found
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You can't upgrade from 17.04 to 20.04 or 20.10 because the upgrade path goes to 17.10 which is EOL as well and not available to upgrade to.  You will be looking at an new installation of a supported version.

Comment: Usually once a version goes EOL you have a short time to get the upgrade to a supported version to work.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: There are difficult ways of doing it, but for most people it is easier just to backup data to keep and do a clean install.  Faster, easier and much less chance of something going wonky.